# autocomplete value does not display

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I follow this web site : https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead

I create my input text as :

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="user" id="user" placeholder="autocomplete" />
</div>
```

In my JS script :

$('#user').on("input", function () {
        var login = $("#user").val();

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: "/user/ajaxSearch",
        data: 'login=' + login,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var typeaheadSource = ['John', 'Alex', 'Terry'];
            $('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSource);
        }
    });
});
```

I have no error, but no list display. I debug my code, and the function typeahead was called.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, i forgot attribute "source" on typeahead function. Now I have this error ont typeahead.js : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the plugin correctly. It requires an object as options and the source is one of the item.

Try this:

```
 var typeaheadSource = ['John', 'Alex', 'Terry'];
 $('.typeahead').typeahead({source: typeaheadSource});
```